# how can I set the launch.json when debug the bash shell on vscode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I want to debug the bash shell by bashdb on the vscode ,but it seems to need set the launch.json.

How can I make it.

It seems to edit the scriptPath ...?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To run/debug currently opened script in `IDE` replace `${command.AskForScriptName}` with `${file}` in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Bash-Debug (type in script name)",
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "scriptPath": "${file}",
            "commandLineArguments": "",
            "windows": {
                "bashPath": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
            },
            "linux": {
                "bashPath": "bash"
            },
            "osx": {
                "bashPath": "bash"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also You can hardcode a specific file:

**Linux:**

```
"scriptPath": "${workspaceRoot}/test.sh"
```

**Windows:**

```
"scriptPath": "${workspaceRoot}\\test.sh"
```

Comment: bashdb seems not recognized.

Comment: You'll need to install the bashdb extension.